# Is 'Is it here?' clear and idiomatic

Tags: idiomatic-language

Person 1: I don't live here in the city.

Person 2: You don't? What about your job? **Is it here?**

Person 1: Yes.

Would 'is it here?' be clear and idiomatic in the context to mean 'in the city'? Or would I have to add a verb between 'it' and 'here'?

Comment: You already have the verb *is*.

Comment: "Do you work here?" might be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is why context is helpful.

> What about your job? Is it here?

This basically breaks into two sentences what could be expressed in one: "Is your job here?"

The next question is "what does 'here' refer to." But the previous sentence *used* "here":

> I don't live **here** in the city.

This was a very convenient sentence, because it makes it absolutely crystal clear where he conversation is taking place, and that "here" means "in the city."

When you suggest adding a verb, I think maybe you're thinking of something like "Is it **located** here?" But this isn't necessary, and it has less to do with context than with the verb "to be." *To be*, conjugated here as *is*, can be a helping verb with other verbs or participles, but on its own, it basically means "to exist," and can have many shades of meaning. Pair it with a prepositional phrase about location, and it can mean "to exist in a place." I am here. You are there. The Phillies are in Philadelphia. So "it is here" is enough to mean "it exists in the location we are in now."